# Toll Cost Extension API returning 0.0 for some routes , Issue in the response

Tags: android, routes, here-api, price

I am developing app with trucks rider and driver, I would like to include tollcost into fare, I have tried here's tollcost api https://developer.here.com/documentation/toll-cost/topics/quick-start-find-optimized-route.html

But the problem is I am always getting 0.0 as a Tollcost, only for few routes I can able to get Toll Price.

https://tce.cit.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id=MyAppId&app_code=MyAppCode&waypoint0=11.0168445,76.9558321&waypoint1=11.3410364,77.7171642&mode=traffic;truck&cost_optimize=1

Am I missing anything? I have tried to contact support team,but I can't able to reach support team.

Comment: I had the same issue, I tested in Brazil and some places worked but in USA I tried some places and didn't work. I sent an email to here developer last week but I didn't have response yet

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment regarding server response, but in Android SDK you don't need to call Toll Cost API directly if you are using Premium SDK. For Premium SDK support for Toll Cost API is built in.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics/toll-cost-extension.html